# What is the meaning of chuffing SOS?

Tags: meaning

Gaz & Dave stuck standing on top of the car, which is sinking in water.
One man walking on the land & saw them, but Gaz says "**Not so Bad**" to man
instead of taking help from him. so Dave responded to Gaz like this:

> "Not so bad"? That's not much of a **chuffing SOS!**

Comment: We would say "*are* stuck standing" and "one man *is* walking" (just as you say "is sinking").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is surprisingly complicated!

> Not much of a [X]

This is an idiomatic phrase. It demonstrates the tendency towards understatement that is common in English. *Literally*, it means that the thing is a [X], but not a good one. *Idiomatically*, it means that the thing is a **bad** [X].

In this case, [X] is "SOS": a distress signal. Dave is telling Gaz that his words were a bad distress signal.

> chuffing

Swear words are often used as intensifiers in English. "[Chuffing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chuffing#Adjective)" is not a swear word: it is a euphemistic replacement for one. Dave may have been avoiding swearing, or *the writer* may have been avoiding it while the audience is supposed to understand that Dave was really swearing.

In either case, it still functions as an intensifier. Gaz's words were a **really** bad distress signal.

Comment: Note that _chuffing_ is not common in AmE - I have only heard it in British television shows.  Can a BrE speaker weigh in on how vulgar it is considered?  (Perhaps you know, @TimPederick)

Comment: @Adam: Definitely not Australian English either, so while I *think* it's fairly tame, I could be very wrong! The Wiktionary page I linked marks it *England* and calls it "mild".